# I am stuck the facebook graph-academy in the section graph-api-basics/10/

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to solve the last exercise in the graph academy of facebook developer page,  https://developers.facebook.com/graph-academy/graph-api-basics/10/ but when i was asked to:

"GET call using the value from the next field." i cannot get the excersice well done, because i get a full url in the value for paging.next

my code is:

```
    // Graph API Basics
    // Lesson 10 - Pagination
    // The FBID of the Facebook page is 20531316728 or facebook.
    FB.api('/facebook/posts', 'GET', {}, function(response) {
      var paging = response.paging;
      log(paging);
      log(paging.next);
    );
    FB.api('/facebook/posts', 'GET', {}, function(response) {   
    });
```

the last part, FB.api, is my best try, but when i put the value on paging.next is a full url, i have tryied copy the entire url inside the brackets, or replacing responce variable,  anyone can give me a hint?

Also i have tried this, it is working on the js sdk console, but it is not the expected result, the green checkmark is not triggered.[this is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HD2EN.png)

```
    // Graph API Basics
    // Lesson 10 - Pagination
    // The FBID of the Facebook page is 20531316728 or facebook.
    FB.api('/facebook/posts', 'GET', {}, function(response) {
      var paging = response.paging;
      log(paging);
      log(paging.next);
    );
    FB.api('paging.next', 'GET', {}, function(response) {   
    });
```

Comment: `FB.api(paging.next, 'GET', ...)` …?

Comment: yes, it have tried this, like this.

    // Graph API Basics

    // Lesson 10 - Pagination


    // The FBID of the Facebook page is 20531316728 or facebook.


    FB.api('/facebook/posts', 'GET', {}, function(response) {

    var paging = response.paging;

    log(paging);

    log(paging.next);



    FB.api(paging.next, 'GET', {}, function(response) {});


    });

Comment: The trouble it is that it seems that it is not the results awaited by the test, there is no green checkmark

Answer (score 1):

Why your answer won't work:

```
 FB.api('paging.next', 'GET', {}, function(response) {   
});
```

First of, 'paging.next' is just a string. Secondly it is outside the callback function which is outside the callback scope.

Here's the way I answered it.

```
FB.api('/facebook/posts', 'GET', {}, function(response) {
  var paging = response.paging;
  log(paging.next);
  FB.api(paging.next);  //paging.next object is to be passed to the next api call.
});
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

They just wanted to log first and second pagination object. Try the code below:

```
FB.api('/facebook/posts', 'GET', {}, function(response1) {
    var paging = response1.paging;
    log(paging);
    FB.api(paging.next, '', {}, function(response2) {
        log(response2.paging);
    });
});
```